# perl missing dependencies for request tracker installation

Tags: perl, dependencies, rt

```
/usr/bin/perl ./sbin/rt-test-dependencies --verbose --with-mysql --with-fastcgi
perl:
        >=5.10.1(5.18.2) ...found
users:
        rt group (www-data) ...found
        bin owner (root) ...found
        libs owner (root) ...found
        libs group (bin) ...found
        web owner (www-data) ...found
        web group (www-data) ...found
CLI dependencies:
        Term::ReadLine ...found
        HTTP::Request::Common ...found
        Term::ReadKey ...found
        Getopt::Long >= 2.24 ...found
        Text::ParseWords ...found
        LWP ...found
CORE dependencies:
        Plack::Handler::Starlet ...MISSING
        Errno ...found
        Devel::GlobalDestruction ...found
        Date::Extract ...MISSING
                Can't locate Clone.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Clone module) (@INC
contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
/usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18
/usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/DateTime/Format/Natural/Expand.pm line 7.
        Crypt::Eksblowfish ...MISSING
        Text::Password::Pronounceable ...found
        Regexp::IPv6 ...found
        Digest::base ...found
        Data::GUID ...MISSING
        DateTime >= 0.44 ...found
        File::Glob ...found
        HTTP::Message >= 6.0 ...found
        HTML::Quoted ...found
        Regexp::Common ...found
        DateTime::Format::Natural ...MISSING
                Attempt to reload DateTime/Format/Natural.pm aborted.
        Tree::Simple >= 1.04 ...found
        Sys::Syslog >= 0.16 ...found
        Class::Accessor >= 0.34 ...found
        File::ShareDir ...found
        CGI::Cookie >= 1.20 ...found
        CGI::Emulate::PSGI ...found
        Log::Dispatch >= 2.30 ...found
        UNIVERSAL::require ...found
        Storable >= 2.08 ...found
        HTML::FormatText::WithLinks >= 0.14 ...found
        Mail::Mailer >= 1.57 ...found
        Encode >= 2.64 ...MISSING
        Email::Address >= 1.897 ...found
        Scalar::Util ...found
        Apache::Session >= 1.53 ...found
        Digest::SHA ...found
        HTML::FormatText::WithLinks::AndTables ...found
        Locale::Maketext::Lexicon >= 0.32 ...found
        Time::ParseDate ...found
        Plack >= 1.0002 ...found
        Digest::MD5 >= 2.27 ...found
        Email::Address::List >= 0.02 ...found
        DBI >= 1.37 ...found
        Locale::Maketext >= 1.06 ...found
        HTML::RewriteAttributes >= 0.05 ...found
        List::MoreUtils ...found
        Time::HiRes ...found
        DBIx::SearchBuilder >= 1.65 ...MISSING
        File::Temp >= 0.19 ...found
        Symbol::Global::Name >= 0.04 ...found
        HTML::Mason::PSGIHandler >= 0.52 ...MISSING
        CGI >= 3.38 ...found
        JSON ...found
        Text::Wrapper ...found
        HTML::Scrubber >= 0.08 ...found
        HTML::Entities ...found
        Module::Refresh >= 0.03 ...found
        Devel::StackTra
DASHBOARDS dependencies:
        URI >= 1.59 ...found
        URI::QueryParam ...found
        MIME::Types ...found
FASTCGI dependencies:
        FCGI::ProcManager ...found
        FCGI >= 0.74 ...MISSING
GPG dependencies:
        File::Which ...found
        PerlIO::eol ...MISSING
        GnuPG::Interface ...found
ICAL dependencies:
        Data::ICal ...found
MAILGATE dependencies:
        Getopt::Long ...found
        LWP::Protocol::https ...found
        LWP::UserAgent >= 6.0 ...found
        Crypt::SSLeay ...MISSING
        Mozilla::CA ...found
        Pod::Usage ...found
        Net::SSL ...MISSING
MYSQL dependencies:
        DBD::mysql >= 2.1018 ...found
SMIME dependencies:
        String::ShellQuote ...found
        File::Which ...found
        Crypt::X509 ...found
USERLOGO dependencies:
        Convert::Color ...found

SOME DEPENDENCIES WERE MISSING.
MAILGATE missing dependencies:
        Crypt::SSLeay ...MISSING
        Net::SSL ...MISSING
GPG missing dependencies:
        PerlIO::eol ...MISSING
FASTCGI missing dependencies:
        FCGI >= 0.74 ...MISSING
CORE missing dependencies:
        DBIx::SearchBuilder >= 1.65 ...MISSING
        Data::GUID ...MISSING
        Date::Extract ...MISSING
                Can't locate Clone.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Clone module) (@INC
contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
/usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18
/usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2/DateTime/Format/Natural/Expand.pm line 7.
        HTML::Mason::PSGIHandler >= 0.52 ...MISSING
        Crypt::Eksblowfish ...MISSING
        Plack::Handler::Starlet ...MISSING
        HTML::Mason >= 1.43 ...MISSING
        Encode >= 2.64 ...MISSING
        DateTime::Format::Natural ...MISSING
                Attempt to reload DateTime/Format/Natural.pm aborted.
        XML::RSS >= 1.05 ...MISSING

Perl library path for /usr/bin/perl:
    /etc/perl
    /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
    /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
    /usr/lib/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
    /usr/lib/perl/5.18
    /usr/share/perl/5.18
    /usr/local/lib/site_perl
    .
```

I am installing request tracker in my ubuntu LAMP server. I am getting error missing dependencies. I tried many ways to resolve it but not working. while installing modules make error coming and showing impossible.
these are the missing dependencies.

Comment: There are many ways to install Perl and Perl modules; which way are you using here?

Comment: Did you try adding the `--install` flag? `/usr/bin/perl ./sbin/rt-test-dependencies --verbose --with-mysql --with-fastcgi --install`

Answer (score 0):

first install the cpan and upgrade it.
cpan> upgrade
then

> cpan
>   install `required dependency`

It may not work for some dependencies.Then install manually like this

> apt-get install lib`required dependencies- requireddependencies`-perl

you can get dependencies here[names & details of perl modules](http://www.livejournal.com/doc/server/lj.install.perl_setup.modules.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how the script `rt-test-dependencies` should work. To show you the missing dependencies. To install RT you should do what the README says:

1. configure [parameters]
2. make testdeps
3. make fixdeps

Don't forget to run `apt-get install build-essential` first otherwise some perl modules won't compile. And of course have CPAN (or rather cpanminus) installed. When using cpanminus, you should then set:

```
export RT_FIX_DEPS_CMD=/usr/bin/cpanm
```